# Set Min and Max height of items in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, scroll, itemscontrol

I am using an ItemsControl to display a list of 1 - 10 items (usually 2 - 4). I am trying to satisfy all these requirements:

- All rows must be the same height
- All rows should be displayed at a height of 300 maximum if possible.
- If there is not enough room to display all rows at 300 high, then display at the largest possible height.
- If the largest possible height is less than 150, then display at maxsize and use a scrollbar
- If the rows do not fill the page, then it must be vertically aligned at the top

This is what I have so far:

```
<Window x:Class="TestGridRows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestGridRows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MainViewModel}"
        Height="570" Width="800">

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border MinHeight="150" MaxHeight="300" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TheNameToDisplay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

This is what it currently looks like with 1 item:
[image: actual1]

and this is what it **should** look like:
[image: expected1]

---

2 or 3 items display as expected:
[image: actual3]

---

For 4+ items, the scrollbar appears correctly but the items are all sized to 150, rather than 300:
[image: actual4]

## Question

How do I align the content to top when there is only 1 item? (without breaking the other functionality obviously)

**Bonus question:** How do I get the items to resize to maxheight instead of minheight when there are 4+ items?

Comment: In general `MinHeight` works in this way that if your item height has a value less than the minimum defined it shows the min and same goes for `MaxHeight`. So what you get is totally expected. Your items probably have Height value lower than your mean (200).

Comment: @LionKing My project has an ActualHeight of 570 for the ScrollViewer. I have been experimenting with 1,2,3 and 5 rows and they all exhibit the same behaviour

Comment: @JumpingJezza: It sounds like you want to use a Grid as the Panel for the ItemsControl: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html

Comment: How about. Replace scrollviewer with grid, itemscontrol with listbox. Set verticalalignment top on listbox.  Calculate the row height in view or viewmodel and set in style.

Comment: @Andy if I replace the scrollviewer then how do I scroll with 4+ items?

Comment: Listbox has a built in scrollviewer appears when the items don't fit

Comment: @Andy that does indeed scroll and align top, but then the items are always minimum size. I really don't want to have calculate row height manually - I've done that before and it is extremely flaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the WPF layout process, measuring and arranging will be done in order. In most cast, if an `UIElement` has variable size, it will return minimum required as result. But if any layout alignment has been set to `Stretch`, `UIElement` will take as possible as it can in that direction in arranging. In your case, `UniFormGrid` will always return 160(which is `Border.MinHeight` + `Border.Margin.Top` + `Border.Margin.Bottom`) * the count of items as desired height in measuring result(which will stored in `DesiredSize.DesiredSize.Height`). But it will take `ItemsControl.ActualHeight` as arranged height since it has `Stretch` `VerticalAlignment`. So, if `UniFormGrid.DesiredSize.Height` was less then `ItemsControl.ActualHeight`, `UniFormGrid` and any child has `Stretch` `VerticalAlignment` will be stretch in vertically, until it encountered its `MaxHeight`. This is why your 1 item test resulted in the center. If you change `UniFormGrid.VerticalAlignment` or `Border.VerticalAlignment` to `Top`, you will get a 160 height item in the top of `ItemsContorl`.

---

The most simple solution to both questions is override the measuring result base on maximum row height and minimum row height. I write the codes in below and had done some basic tests, it seems to work just fine.

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class MyScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
    {
        public double DesiredViewportHeight;

        public MyScrollViewer() : base() { }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            // record viewport's height for late calculation 
            DesiredViewportHeight = constraint.Height;

            var result = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

            // make sure that `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` will get correct value 
            if (ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible && ExtentHeight <= ViewportHeight)
                result = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class MyUniformGrid : UniformGrid
    {
        private MyScrollViewer hostSV;
        private ItemsControl hostIC;

        public MyUniFormGrid() : base() { }

        public double MaxRowHeight { get; set; }
        public double MinRowHeight { get; set; }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            if (hostSV == null)
            {
                hostSV = VisualTreeHelperEx.GetAncestor<MyScrollViewer>(this);
                hostSV.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.HeightChanged)
                    {
                        // need to redo layout pass after the height of host had changed.  
                        this.InvalidateMeasure();
                    }
                };
            }

            if (hostIC == null)
                hostIC = VisualTreeHelperEx.GetAncestor<ItemsControl>(this);

            var viewportHeight = hostSV.DesiredViewportHeight;
            var rows = hostIC.Items.Count;
            var rowHeight = viewportHeight / rows;
            double desiredHeight = 0;

            // calculate the correct height
            if (rowHeight > MaxRowHeight || rowHeight < MinRowHeight)
                desiredHeight = MaxRowHeight * rows;
            else
                desiredHeight = viewportHeight;

            var result = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

            return new Size(result.Width, desiredHeight);
        }
    }

    public class VisualTreeHelperEx
    {
        public static T GetAncestor<T>(DependencyObject reference, int level = 1) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (level < 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(level));

            return GetAncestorInternal<T>(reference, level);
        }

        private static T GetAncestorInternal<T>(DependencyObject reference, int level) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(reference);

            if (parent == null)
                return null;

            if (parent is T && --level == 0)
                return (T)parent;

            return GetAncestorInternal<T>(parent, level);
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="570" Width="800">

    <local:MyScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl>
            <sys:String>aaa</sys:String>
            <sys:String>aaa</sys:String>
            <sys:String>aaa</sys:String>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <local:MyUniformGrid Columns="1"  MinRowHeight="150" MaxRowHeight="300" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </local:MyScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Works perfectly!